# How to use REGEXP_SUBSTR properly?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-substr

Currently in my select statement I have id and value. The value is json which looks like this:

`{"layerId":"nameOfLayer","layerParams":{some unnecessary data}`

I would like to have in my select id and `nameOfLayer` so the output would be for example:

```
1, layerName
2, layerName2
etc.
```

The json looks always the same so the layerID is the first.
Could you tell me how can I use REGEXP_SUBSTR properly in my select query which looks like this now?

```
select
  id,
  value
from
  ...
where
  table1.id = table2.bookmark_id
  and ...;
```

Comment: Why not use JSON functions?

Comment: What do you mean by json functions? The value is varchar type. @GordonLinoff

Comment: @ErykJanocha https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973

Comment: @ThomasStrub I would like to use regexp_substr if possible.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 11g, you can extract the `layerId` using the following regular expression, where `js` is the name of your JSON column:

```
regexp_replace(js, '^.*"layerId":"([^"]+).*$', '\1')
```

This basically extracts the string between double quotes after `"layerId":`.

In more recent versions, you would add a check constraint on the table to ensure that the document is valid JSON, and then use the dot notation to access the object attribute as follows:

```
create table mytable (
    id int primary key,
    js varchar2(200),
    constraint ensure_js_is_json check (js is json)
);

insert into mytable values (1, '{"layerId":"nameOfLayer","layerParams":{} }');

select id, t.js.layerId from mytable t;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dc35747221672f5625897b276cbed4cd)**:

```
ID | LAYERID    
-: | :----------
 1 | nameOfLayer
```

Comment: For this JSON `{"layerId":"nameOfLayer","layerParams":{"layerId":"NOT THIS ONE!"}}` the regular expression gets the wrong value and for this JSON `{"layerId":"Quoted \"String\"","layerParams":{}}` it truncates the field at the first quote. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d868e6c767796f329d1feb70aa1587cd)

Comment: @GMB Forunately in layerParams there is no another layerID strring.

Comment: @ErykJanocha: good, so the regexp I provided you with would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions; use a `JSON_TABLE` or `JSON_VALUE` to parse JSON:

**Oracle 18c Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data (
  id    INTEGER,
  value VARCHAR2(4000)
);

INSERT INTO test_data ( id, value )
SELECT 1, '{"layerId":"nameOfLayer","layerParams":{"some":"unnecessary data"}}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '{"layerParams":{"layerId":"NOT THIS ONE!"},"layerId":"nameOfLayer"}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '{"layerId":"Name with \"Quotes\"","layerParams":{"layerId":"NOT THIS ONE!"}}' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       j.layerId
FROM   test_data t
       CROSS JOIN
       JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$'
         COLUMNS (
           layerId VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.layerId'
         )
       ) j
```

**Query 2**:

If you only want a single value you could, alternatively, use `JSON_VALUE`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       JSON_VALUE( value, '$.layerId' ) AS layerId
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

Both output:

> ```
> ID | LAYERID           
> -: | :-----------------
>  1 | nameOfLayer       
>  2 | nameOfLayer       
>  3 | Name with "Quotes"
> ```

**Query 3**:

You can try regular expressions but they do not always work as expected:

```sql
SELECT id,
       REPLACE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '[{,]"layerId":"((\\"|[^"])*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ),
         '\"',
         '"'
       ) AS layerID
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | LAYERID           
> -: | :-----------------
>  1 | nameOfLayer       
>  2 | NOT THIS ONE!     
>  3 | Name with "Quotes"
> ```

So if you can guarantee that no-one is going to put data into the database where the JSON is in a different order then this may work; however the JSON specification allows key-value pairs to be in any order so regular expressions are not a general solution that will parse every JSON string. You should be using a proper JSON parser and there are 3rd party solutions available for Oracle 11g or you can upgrade to Oracle 12c where there is a native solution.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f58c50c4731cfa63790adc30f895420)*

Comment: Sorry, I have got Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `regexp_substr` like this:

```
regexp_substr(str, '[^"]+',1,2) as layer_id,
regexp_substr(str, '[^"]+',1,4) as layername
```

[Db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4d2b3914fafbb2dc34ab85f664bf4279)

Cheers!!

Comment: This doesn't work if you have quotes within strings such as `{"3":"name with \"Quotes\"","layerparams2"}` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4a21e49a815595f3350b6e0b89238a1a)